# How does ReactJS prop binding work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following a value (`<ArticleList instance>.props.articles`) is bound to a prop of `HomePage` (`this.props.articles`).

The object identity of `this.props.articles` might be `undefined` or it might change, so ReactJS must maintain "this.props.articles" as *configuration* instead of an object reference, permitting dynamic look-up.

Is this correct?

```
class HomePage extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <ArticleList articles={this.props.articles} />
  }
}

function ArticleList({articles}) { 
  if(!articles) return <div>There are no articles!</div>;
  return <div>{ articles.map(a => <Article value={a} />) }</div>;
}
```

**Edit:** I have edited the code to cover the case for `undefined`. My question remains.

**To restate:**

`this.props.articles` looks like a JavaScript expression to retrieve the value of a property.

But it cannot be for the reason stated in the question (you'd be binding undefined).

So is this instead special JSX syntax that JSX knows how to parse?

Comment: It's almost correct. Consider this : if `this.props.articles` is falsy, what do you get back from your `ArticleList` component? Would it not break because you are trying to `map` something which you should not?

Comment: If, say, `this.props.articles` was `undefined`, you'd get an "undefined is not an object" error or similar as you try and invoke `map` on `undefined`. If it was `false`, then you'd get something like "undefined is not a function" as `false` would be boxed and there would be no `map` method.

Comment: Picking nits, but I think you will get an error anyway because JavaScript inside of JSX needs to be wrapped in curly brackets:
`return <div>{articles.map(a => <Article value={a} />)}</div>;`

Comment: Exactly, here we should return conditionally and check for both cases. Or I am not getting the question here?

Comment: @hellojeffhall Ah thank you for the correction.

Comment: To restate the question: `this.props.articles` looks like a JavaScript expression to retrieve the value of a property. But it cannot be for the reason stated in the question (you'd be binding `undefined`). So is this instead special JSX synatx that JSX knows how to parse?

Comment: @BenAston I think I get your question. So, if `this.props.articles` is undefined, your function `ArticleList` would receive `undefined` and in there, you need to check and _render conditionally_ . Check this link to know more : https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/

Comment: No. My question is: `this.props.articles` looks like a JavaScript expression, but it cannot be. So does JSX store this as a string and maintain it as configuration internally instead, for lazy evaluation later? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you saying that `this.props.articles` is not JavaScript?

Your code once transpiled by Babel becomes:

```
class HomePage extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(ArticleList, {
      articles: this.props.articles,
    });
  }
}

function ArticleList({articles}) { 
  if(!articles) {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, 'There are no articles!');
  }
  return React.createElement('div', {},
    articles.map(a => <Article value={a} />)
  );
}
```

`this.props.articles` is simply a reference to the `props` property of the `HomePage` class.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So it is not evaluated at the time of writing the JSX. Instead it is used to construct a function containing the expression that is evaluated each time `render` is invoked.